# Как разрезать 3d-объект на множество 2d-картинок?

Tags: 3d

Есть 3d-фигура, необходимо разрезать ее на множество картинок одинаковой толщины (3 мм) для последующей печати на обычном принтере. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: То есть, написать слайсер?

Comment: Ну, или во всяком случае найти. Слайсеры конвертируют в STL, а мне надо в jpg

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: stl - это 3д формат. jpg - это 3д картинка. Слайсер нарезает 3d модель (обычно это stl) в gcode (который в теории можно аккуратно конвернуть в серию jpg/png/bmp

Comment: окей, есть gcode, как его конвертнуть в серию jpg?